# If/Elif/Else statement issue. If if and elif not met, not going into else

Tags: python, if-statement

sorry for the probably extremely obvious question, but I've been having trouble with this if/elif/else statement.  The statement never proceeds into the "else" area.  Even if difference is equal to 0.

```
    if difference > 0:
        difference_string = "The combination will have a %s cm gap from being fully enclosed." % (difference)
    elif difference < 0:
        difference_string = "The combination will exceed the dimensions of the shelf unit by %s cm." % (difference)
    else:
        difference_string = "The combination completely enclose a %s cm shelf unit." % (uh)
```

I don't get what's not right.  I guess I could just do elif == 0, but I want to understand my error before I work on fixing it.

Here is the whole code:

```
def x38door_fit(uh):
    """uh = unit height
    door_fit(uh) --> x*38 door heights will fit on uh.
    """
    uh = int(uh)
    doors = uh / int(38)
    if uh % int(38) is not 0:
        tuh = 0
        counter = 0
        d38 = int(38)
        while tuh < uh:
            d38 += 38
            tuh = d38
            counter += 1
        tdh = counter * 38      #total door height = tdh
        difference = uh - tdh
        if difference > 0:
            difference_string = "The combination will have a %s cm gap from being fully enclosed." % (difference)
        elif difference < 0:
            difference_string = "The combination will exceed the dimensions of the shelf unit by %s cm." % (difference)
        else:
            difference_string = "The combination completely enclose a %s cm shelf unit." % (uh)
        print difference_string
        print doors 
    return doors
```

Comment: Could you give us a runnable example that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: `print(repr(difference))` immediately before the `if` may be enlightening.

Comment: use `str % (v,)` for string interpolation

Comment: is `difference` a `float`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this line of code:

```
if uh % int(38) is not 0:
```

If you pass in `0`, which is assigned to `uh`, this conditional evaluates to 0. Your `if/else` block in question is never executed because it never reached.

Comment: Ty.  Didn't even think of that.  ^o^

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `difference` is a float. The typical problem is shown below

```
>>> 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 - 0.3 == 0
False
```

This is because most decimal fractions can't be represented exactly as floats.

One possible fix would be to replace your `float` with `Decimal`

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> Decimal('0.1') + Decimal('0.1') + Decimal('0.1') - Decimal('0.3') == 0
True
```

Another is to allow for a small error. ie. treat very small numbers as zero

```
>>> abs(0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 - 0.3) < 1e-10
True
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided a runnable example, so I will provide as clear of an answer as I can:

One possibility is that `difference` is a string. You can check this by typing in `print repr(difference)` before your `if` statement, to get what `difference` is.

```
>>> difference = '9'
>>> print repr(difference)
'9'
>>> difference = 9
>>> print repr(difference):
9
```

Comment: Added it above, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually two things which are causing you grief here, neither of which have been explained properly.

First of all, on this line,

```
if uh % int(38) is not 0:
```

if `uh` is *any* multiple of 38 is passed in, the entirety of the logic will be skipped. So 38, 76, 114, etc... will all be passed through and nothing will be printed.

Secondly, apart from being wildly bad design with numerous unused variables, with this code:

```
tuh = 0
counter = 0
d38 = int(38)
while tuh < uh:
    d38 += 38
    tuh = d38
    counter += 1
tdh = counter * 38
```

will never allow a difference of more than 0 to occur. It appears you are trying to find the closet multiple of 38 to `uh` here. Lets simplify it up a little. We can remove `d38` and just reassign the commands that alter it to `tuh` and get rid of `counter` completely.

```
tuh = 0
while tuh < uh:
    tuh += 38
tdh = tuh
```

Now, as long as `tuh` is less than `uh` we will add another 38, so `tuh` (and `tdh`) will *always* be greater than `uh`, in every case. Which means the only case that will ever be executed is this one, since `difference = uh - tdh` :

```
elif difference < 0:
    difference_string = "The combination will exceed the dimensions of the shelf unit by %s cm." % (difference)
```